# How to get data from a form and store it in a variable in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, get

So here is the form class in views.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=10)
```

The form is added to the concerned page as:

```
<form action="/encyclopedia/search.html" method="get">
                <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                {{ form }}
</form>
```

I've tried to implement the view function in two ways:
first:-

```
def search(request):
form = SearchForm(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    query = form.cleaned_data['query']
else:
    query = None
return HttpResponse(query)
```

second:-

```
def search(request):
form = SearchForm(request.GET)
query = request.GET.get("query")
return HttpResponse(query)
```

The given HttpResponse is just to check if i have successfully got the desired data inside variable "query". In both ways, it simply returns None.
I see methods to get data from POST all over the internet. Am i missing something here???
I've tried so many things.
Can someone please just write a function they would use to get data from a form using GET method? I will really appreciate it. I have no idea what else to do now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the parameter is `q`, since the HTML component is:

```
<input … name="q" … >
```

You thus can access it with:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    return HttpResponse(query)
```

or you can use a `Form`:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=10)
```

and work with:

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        query = form.cleaned_data['q']
    else:
        query = None
    return HttpResponse(query)
```

**Note**: As is written in the [section on *Design your urls*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/overview/#design-your-urls).

> Django encourages beautiful URL design and doesn’t put any cruft in URLs, like .php or .asp.

You thus might want to remove the `.html` suffix in your paths.